# Discussing regression results in a frequentist framework

Tags: confidence-interval, frequentist, reporting

There have been excellent debates about how to discuss treatment effects in a frequentist framework, for example: [Language for communicating frequentist results about treatment effects](https://discourse.datamethods.org/t/language-for-communicating-frequentist-results-about-treatment-effects/934)

What about regression coefficients?

**"Positive" study** could report a point estimate for OR is 1.3 with 95% CIs of [0.6-2]. I guess the following statement is very widely used: *"Variable X was associated to increased odds of having outcome Y"*. But would this be more accurate: *"A zero effect of variable X on odds of having outcome Y could be rule out at 0.05 level"*?

**"Negative" study** instead could report an OR of 1.1, 95% CI being 0.7 - 1.5 or a regression coefficient B = 0.5 with 95% CIs of -1.0 - 2.0. Following statement come up all the time but aren´t they incorrect and confusing?

*"Variable X did not have increased odds for outcome Y"*

*"Variable X was not associated to outcome Y"*

*"Variable X did not predict outcome Y"*

So, what is the correct and accurate method to discuss "positive" and "negative" study result, and what is the general/agnostic language?

Comment: I don't think we need to think too hard about this.  That blog post on datamethods can be applied to regression coefficients.

Comment: (3), (4), and (5) are questionable, because they implicitly conflate significance with effect size.  Regardless, would there be some way you could condense what appear to be five separate questions into a single, clear, focused question?

Comment: @whuber I tried to condense

Comment: Thank you.  But since regression coefficients *are* (treatment) effects, it's hard to see how you are distinguishing your question from the material you reference.

Comment: @whuber We were unable to find evidence against the hypothesis that A equals B with the current sample size. = We were unable to find evidence against the hypothesis that regression coefficient B equals 0 (?) = We were unable to find evidence against the hypothesis X does not effect Y (?)

Comment: In a regression context, "X does not affect Y" has no operational meaning, because regression concerns estimating conditional distributions, not causal relationships.  As far as comparing the means of two groups A and B goes, that can be accomplished by combining the data and creating an indicator variable to designate which group each value comes from: you then regress the data against the indicator and test the regression coefficient against zero.